# (Rails 4.0.1) "has_one" nested model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, fields-for

After following few different guides I am still getting troubles with nesting one model **addr** within form of other **hotel**.
I wasable to get working form before which created db row for **hotels**, but didn't one for **addr**.
After I added *@hotel.addrs.build* to my controller, I am getting an error

> undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
>   on this line.

My code:

hotels.rb

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :addrs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addrs
end
```

addr.rb

```
class Addr < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hotel
end
```

hotels_controller.rb

```
def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    @hotel.addrs.build
end
...
def hotel_params
    params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, :rate, addrs_atributes: [:street, :build])
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :hotels do
    resources :addr
end
```

_form.erb.html

```
... </div>
<%= fields_for :addr do |l| %>
    Street <%= l.text_field :street %><br>
    No. <%= l.number_field :build %>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Please suggest what could be wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `has_one :addr` - the plural would be more logical for `has_many` rather than `has_one`. Of course, it's a while since I used Rails so that could be crazy talk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
 has_one :addr
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addr
```

in controller new action

```
 @hotel.build_addr
```

in hotel_params

```
 params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, :rate, addr_atributes: [:street, :build])
```

in view

```
<%= f.fields_for :addr do |addr|%> 

<%end%>
```

Comment: Thanks NitinJ.
Ofcourse it should be addr instead of addrs. But I was having troubles with addr too. 
Anyway, I did everything You adviced and now I am getting "unknown attribute: hotel_id" in the controller on @hotel.build_addr line.

Comment: do you write @hotel = Hotel.new before that line . Also do you have hotel_id field in addr table?

Comment: @hotel = Hotel.new was there. I just added "t.integer :hotel_id" line to create_addrs.rb table - I am getting the same issue.

Comment: check in db/schema file that you have hotel_id in table name addrs

Comment: that wasn't there. I tried to put it there, but still having error

Comment: you have to create a migration for that and run that migration

Comment: Thanks a lot,@NitinJ, this worked and form at hotels/new is displaying. But after I save it, I get Hotel stuff saved and Addr data doesn't save.

Comment: can you tell me the params you are receiving in create method and also code of create method

Comment: "def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(hotel_params)
"
 
AND

"def hotel_params
      params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, :rate, addr_atributes: [:street, :build])
end"

Comment: you have addr_atributes spelling wrong it should be addr_attributes. and i am asking about params you are receiving in controller you can find them in development logs

Comment: My params - 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T+BHxvZDQERr29Trw760+WceQEe1aKBvTpNTovY7SfA=", "hotel"=>{"name"=>"ee", "rate"=>"77", "addr_attributes"=>{"street"=>"5y", "build"=>"7"}}, "commit"=>"Create Hotel"}
__
After fixing misspelling I got my Addr data in database, with id of hotel.
But now I got other problem, I cannot display my @addr.street on show page as I can not figure out what params should I put into show method in the controller. I have now:
  'def show
    (at)addr = Addr.find(params[:id])
  end' which ofcourse gives me "Couldn't find Addr with id=9".